# How to measure time of parsing JSON string into Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, timing

I'm using AJAX query to get some long array from server side.
The array is really big (let's say million elements), so even HTTP query takes a time, I see it in a console. 
But after the query is done, some time passes until I see an output which comes from a callback function of AJAX query.

I try to measure some time inside that function, but the time difference is miserable and doesn't look like referring to the whole process.
(If I put time brackets outside AJAX querying function I get anyway a zero which is clear why)
Inspecting of Firebug profiler results also didn't give me a glue..

Here is my code (I use jQuery):

```
$.getJSON(
    'some-url',
    '',
    function(data) {
        var start = (new Date).getTime();
        console.log(data.length);
        var end = (new Date).getTime();
        console.log((end - start) /1000); // for 1M array gives something like 0.03 s
    }
);
```

So I want to catch a time of the whole process happening in browser's engine related to dealing with that object.
How can I do that?

Comment: Don't pass an array of a million items; that's A Bad Idea™.

Comment: Perhaps moving the start time before $.getJSON and leaving the end time on the onComplete() event? Also make the var start a global variable.

Comment: Using `.getJSON`, you can't time the JSON parsing because that's happening inside jQuery code.

Comment: firebug api define the 2 following call

console.time('string');
console.timeEnd('string');

Answer (score 2):

Use `ajax` , not `getJSON`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'some-url',
   dataType: 'text',
   success: function(jsonText) {           
       console.log(jsonText.length);
       var start = (new Date).getTime();

       var data = $.parseJSON(jsonText);  

       var end = (new Date).getTime();
       console.log((end - start) /1000); // for 1M array gives something like 0.03 s
   }
});
```

Comment: Right on. How I didn't guessed that by myself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your answer correctly, you want to measure the time it takes to process the response. I looks like callback passed to $.getJSON is called after the response JSON is parsed. You will need to use a different method, perhaps $.ajax. The following code should also work (untested):

```
function initiateGetRequest(url, callback)
    var req;
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === 4) {
            callback(req.responseText, req.status);
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
}

function processMyJSONResponse(responseText, statusCode) {
    var startTime;        
    var myResponseObject;
    if (statusCode === 200) {
        startTime = Date.now();
        // Processing logic here
        myResponseObject = JSON.parse(responseText);

        console.log((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong, statusCode: " + statusCode);
    }
}

// somewhere else
initiateGetRequest("myUrl", processMyJSONResponse);
```

Comment: Yeah, that code works.
 It shows same time as jQuery.ajax.
 
 Well, it turned out not so hard to process a JSON array with 1M entries - about 0.23s (6 MB; just numbers, but still).
 So most time required is to get actual data (serveral megabytes) not to parsed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: [create a jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/). It allows running asynchronous or “deferred” tests.

Alternatively, you could use [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) and set up a test case manually.

Don’t simply compare two `new Date` timestamps, as [this is not an accurate way of measuring things across all browsers and devices](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-benchmarking).

Comment: Gotta give a look to that.
For a while must say that I have rather high overall times so can live with simple Date's at first.